# How do I design a generic trait that can operate on `Self:!Copy` and `Self=&mut[S]`

Tags: generics, rust, traits, borrow-checker, mutability

I am trying to implement some custom traits, and in some cases I'm implementing for `&mut [T]`.  The problem is that the trait method uses `&self` and this results in a double reference.  I can't use plain `self`, or I will be prevented from implementing for `T:!Copy`.  The simple example is

```
fn llama(message: &&mut [char])
{
    (*message)[0] = 'b';
}

fn main()
{
    let mut message: Vec<char> = "Rust".chars().collect();
    let m2:&mut [char] = &mut message;

    llama(&m2);
}
```

which gives me

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `message[_]` which is behind a `&` reference
```

A more complex example (still not as complex as the library I am developing) that led me to this point is

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3A%7BDisplay%2C%20Write%7D%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3AFromIterator%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Wood%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%3A%20Display%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drill(%26self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AT%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Orange%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20val%3A%20i32%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Wood%20for%20Orange%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%20%3D%20String%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drill(%26self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AT%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format!(%22%7B%7Dw%22%2C%20self.val)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CS%3E%20Wood%20for%20Vec%3CS%3E%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20S%3A%20Wood%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%20%3D%20String%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drill(%26self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AT%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20slice%3A%20%26%5BS%5D%20%3D%20self.as_slice()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20rval%3A%20Self%3A%3AT%20%3D%20%3C%26%5BS%5D%20as%20Wood%3E%3A%3Adrill(%26slice)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rval.push(%27v%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rval%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CS%3E%20Wood%20for%20%26%5BS%5D%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20S%3A%20Wood%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%20%3D%20String%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drill(%26self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AT%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20rval%3A%20String%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20o%20in%20*self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(rval%2C%20%22%7B%7D%2C%20%22%2C%20%3CS%20as%20Wood%3E%3A%3Adrill(o)).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rval%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20fn%20pants(x%3A%20%26mut%20%5Bchar%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20ch%20in%20x%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20ch.is_lowercase()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*ch%20%3D%20ch.to_uppercase().next().unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20ch.is_uppercase()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*ch%20%3D%20ch.to_lowercase().next().unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Wood%20for%20%26mut%20%5Bchar%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%20%3D%20String%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drill(%26self)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AT%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpants(*self)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(*self)%5B0%5D%20%3D%20%27n%27%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20String%3A%3Afrom_iter(self.iter())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20oranges%20%3D%20(1..5).map(%7Ci%7C%20Orange%20%7B%20val%3A%20i%20%7D).collect%3A%3A%3CVec%3C_%3E%3E()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20oranges.drill())%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%3A%20%26%5BOrange%5D%20%3D%20%26oranges%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20z.drill())%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20message%3AVec%3C_%3E%20%3D%20%22Rust%22.chars().collect()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20message%3A%26mut%20%5Bchar%5D%20%3D%20%26mut%20message%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20message.drill())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20message.drill())%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20m2%3A%26%26mut%20%5Bchar%5D%20%3D%20%26message%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(*m2)%5B0%5D%20%3D%20%27n%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A)

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Write};
use std::iter::FromIterator;

trait Wood {
    type T: Display;
    fn drill(&self) -> Self::T;
}

struct Orange {
    val: i32,
}

impl Wood for Orange {
    type T = String;

    fn drill(&self) -> Self::T {
        format!("{}w", self.val)
    }
}

impl<S> Wood for Vec<S>
where
    S: Wood,
{
    type T = String;

    fn drill(&self) -> Self::T {
        let slice: &[S] = self.as_slice();
        let mut rval: Self::T = <&[S] as Wood>::drill(&slice);
        rval.push('v');
        rval
    }
}

impl<S> Wood for &[S]
where
    S: Wood,
{
    type T = String;

    fn drill(&self) -> Self::T {
        let mut rval: String = String::new();
        for o in *self {
            write!(rval, "{}, ", <S as Wood>::drill(o)).unwrap();
        }
        rval
    }
}

pub fn pants(x: &mut [char]) {
    for ch in x {
        if ch.is_lowercase() {
            *ch = ch.to_uppercase().next().unwrap();
        } else if ch.is_uppercase() {
            *ch = ch.to_lowercase().next().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

impl Wood for &mut [char] {
    type T = String;

    fn drill(&self) -> Self::T {
        //pants(*self);
        (*self)[0] = 'n';
        String::from_iter(self.iter())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let oranges = (1..5).map(|i| Orange { val: i }).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{}", oranges.drill());

    let z: &[Orange] = &oranges;
    println!("{}", z.drill());

    let mut message:Vec<_> = "Rust".chars().collect();
    let message:&mut [char] = &mut message;
    println!("{}", message.drill());
    println!("{}", message.drill());

    let m2:&&mut [char] = &message;
    (*m2)[0] = 'n';
}
```

When the trait uses `&self` I get the `E0594`, but when it uses `self`, I can't implement it for `&[T:!Copy]` because I get an `` error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*o` which is behind a shared reference ``.  How can I maneuver between this Scylla and Charybdis?

In order to help folks who suspect the XY problem, what I am attempting to do is create a trait that I can use to convert from Rust objects into `JValue`s for the `jni` crate.  That code looks like

```
impl<'a: 'b, 'b> ConvertRustToJValue<'a, 'b> for &[i16] {
    type T = AutoLocal<'a, 'b>;
    fn into_temporary(self, je: &'b JNIEnv<'a>) -> Result<AutoLocal<'a, 'b>, jni::errors::Error> {
        let rval: jshortArray = je.new_short_array(self.len() as jsize)?;
        je.set_short_array_region(rval, 0, self)?;

        Ok(AutoLocal::new(je, JObject::from(rval)))
    }
    fn temporary_into_jvalue(tmp: &AutoLocal<'a, 'b>) -> JValue<'a> {
        JValue::from(tmp.as_obj())
    }
}
```

and it gets used in procedural macros that generate code like

```
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub fn pixelsWhatever(
    &self,
    arg0: &RenderTargetRect,
    arg1: &str,
    arg2: i32,
    arg3: &AffineTransform,
) -> Result<Vec<i8>, jni::errors::Error> {
    use jni_boilerplate_helper::{ConvertJValueToRust, ConvertRustToJValue, JavaSignatureFor};
    #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
    jni_boilerplate_helper::panic_if_bad_sigs(&[
        <&RenderTargetRect as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for(),
        <&str as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for(),
        <i32 as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for(),
        <&AffineTransform as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for(),
        <Vec<i8> as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for(),
    ]);
    let tmp0 = ConvertRustToJValue::into_temporary(arg0, self.jni_env)?;
    let tmp1 = ConvertRustToJValue::into_temporary(arg1, self.jni_env)?;
    let tmp2 = ConvertRustToJValue::into_temporary(arg2, self.jni_env)?;
    let tmp3 = ConvertRustToJValue::into_temporary(arg3, self.jni_env)?;
    let sig = String::from("(")
        + &<&RenderTargetRect as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for()
        + &<&str as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for()
        + &<i32 as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for()
        + &<&AffineTransform as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for()
        + ")"
        + &<Vec<i8> as JavaSignatureFor>::signature_for();
    let results = self.jni_env.call_method(
        self.java_this.as_obj(),
        "pixelsWhatever",
        sig,
        &[
            <&RenderTargetRect as ConvertRustToJValue>::temporary_into_jvalue(&tmp0),
            <&str as ConvertRustToJValue>::temporary_into_jvalue(&tmp1),
            <i32 as ConvertRustToJValue>::temporary_into_jvalue(&tmp2),
            <&AffineTransform as ConvertRustToJValue>::temporary_into_jvalue(&tmp3),
        ],
    )?;
    <Vec<i8> as ConvertJValueToRust>::to_rust(self.jni_env, results)
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with taking `&mut self`?

Comment: If mutating a slice through `&&mut [T]` were allowed, it would be trivial to create mutable aliases, e.g. `let shr1: &&mut [T] = ...; let shr2 = shr1 /* shared refs are Copy */; let (mut1, mut2) = (*shr1, *shr2);`

Comment: I can't take a `&mut self` because often the thing is not actually mutable.

Comment: If the thing is not actually mutable, then `drill()` shouldn't be able to mutate it either. If the thing is sometimes mutable after all, look into interior mutability, specifically the `RefCell` type.

Comment: Also, perhaps you might have a separate method for mutable and for immutable drilling, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=526175153de60c0dcd0284682234953d)? It's really hard to tell without understanding the exact problem you're trying to solve - this is starting to feel like [xy](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Try changing the signature to `fn llama(message: &mut [char])`, or `fn llama(message: &mut &mut [char])`.